# Magento: wysiwyg in custom module, image links are incorrect

Tags: image, magento, upload, wysiwyg

I have a custom module, where I want to add wysiwyg editor to field. 
I do it in this way:

```
    $fieldset->addField('submenu_html', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'submenu_html',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cmsnav')->__('Submenu HTML'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cmsnav')->__('Submenu HTML'),
        'style'     => 'width:500px; height:400px;',
        'wysiwyg'   => true,
        'required'  => false,
        'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
    ));
```

In xml file I added all necessary JS and CSS files.
Editor is working, but then I upload image I get this kind of link:

```
<img src="http://linktoproject/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvVW50aXRsZWQtMS5wbmcifX0,/key/13e9709bba938ba67ff4ab68cb24c7a969aa89da4039bd850d65204116d6e76a/" alt="" />
```

And I can see image only in Mozilla, in other browsers image doesn't load.
I checked config setting which I get on my module page and in CMS Static Block, they are same. Where can be problem? Thank you.

Comment: so, it's didn't show in other browser like Chrome or Safari? Then, I didn't see any local sub image directory for your image folder. That will directly upload to base directory in magento design?

Comment: Yes, Chrome, Safari, IE. Files are uploaded to media/wysiwyg as by default in Magento.

Comment: Chrome and Safari rendering engine is pretty same. I think, problem can file permission or browser setting.

Comment: Otherwise, you can test with Create new CMS page, then, add this image to your new cms page. Then, call this page. At least, you will figure out problem. Hope help :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to change just one setting in admin :

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management -> Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog` to `Yes`

I found that this setting is checked in `/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/WYSIWYG/Images.php` on line 180 ( in Magento 1.7.0.2 ) and depending on that either static or dynamic links are generated.

*P.S. When you said that the link only works in Mozilla, it is because the link has an admin path in it, so you must be logged in the admin panel to be able to see a link. So, as you were only logged in the admin panel through Mozilla, it only worked there.*